# Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a problem when trying to save a pdf using the "pdf_dart" library.
I assume the problem is linked to the image I'm downloading from the internet to try to attach to the pdf but I'm not sure what it is.

### CODE

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:app_formulario/models/Customer.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart' as pdfDart;
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageDart;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as materialDart;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PDFBloc {
  PDFBloc() {
    final Document pdf = Document();

    http
        .get(
            "https://clsp.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-clsp-500px.png")
        .then((onValue) {
      final image = pdfDart.PdfImage(
        pdf.document,
        image: onValue.bodyBytes,
        width: 300,
        height: 150,
      );

      pdf.addPage(Page(build: (Context context) {
        return Center(
          child: Image(image),
        ); // Center
      }));

      criarPDF(pdf);
    });
  }

void criarPDF(Document pdf) async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String appDocPath = appDocDir.path;
    appDocPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rwrd.app_formulario";

    final File file = File('$appDocPath/example.pdf');
    file.writeAsBytesSync(pdf.save());
  }
```

The error happens right when I am going to save the pdf with the image, that is, apparently the image is downloaded normally, however when inserting it in the pdf and trying to save it, the error is caused.

I don't know if the way I'm saving is the correct one, maybe that's it, but unfortunately I can't access the file folder without going all the way through it.

### The error stack

```
E/flutter (18670): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 6307: 6308
E/flutter (18670): #0      Uint8List.[]  (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:2209:7)
E/flutter (18670): #1      PdfImage._prepare 
package:pdf/src/image.dart:183
E/flutter (18670): #2      PdfObject._write 
package:pdf/src/object.dart:53
E/flutter (18670): #3      PdfOutput.write 
package:pdf/src/output.dart:69
E/flutter (18670): #4      SetMixin.forEach  (dart:collection/set.dart:148:30)
E/flutter (18670): #5      PdfDocument._write 
package:pdf/src/document.dart:168
E/flutter (18670): #6      PdfDocument.save 
package:pdf/src/document.dart:176
E/flutter (18670): #7      Document.save 
package:pdf/widgets/document.dart:71
E/flutter (18670): #8      PDFBloc.criarPDF 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:53
E/flutter (18670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18670): #9      new PDFBloc.<anonymous closure> 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:35
E/flutter (18670): #10     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (18670): #11     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (18670): #12     _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
E/flutter (18670): #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
E/flutter (18670): #14     Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
E/flutter (18670): #15     Future._completeWithValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
E/flutter (18670): #16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:32:15)
E/flutter (18670): #17     _completeOnAsyncReturn  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:290:13)
E/flutter (18670): #18     _withClient (package:http/http.dart)
E/flutter (18670): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18670): #19     get 
package:http/http.dart:46
E/flutter (18670): #20     new PDFBloc 
package:app_formulario/blocs/pdfBloc.dart:18
E/flutter (18670): #21     FormBloc._recoverCustomerInformations 
package:app_formulario/blocs/formBloc.dart:37
E/flutter (18670): #22     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
E/flutter (18670): #23     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter (18670): #24     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter (18670): #25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:338:11)
E/flutter (18670): #26     _DelayedData.perform  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:593:14)
E/flutter (18670): #27     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:709:11)
E/flutter (18670): #28     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:669:7)
E/flutter (18670): #29     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1122:38)
E/flutter (18670): #30     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (18670): #31     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (18670): #32     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (18670): #33     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
E/flutter (18670): #34     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
E/flutter (18670): #35     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
E/flutter (18670): #36     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
E/flutter (18670): #37     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
E/flutter (18670): #38     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
E/flutter (18670):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change pdf image widget to this,

```
final image = pdfDart.PdfImage.jpeg(
    pdf.document,
    image: onValue.bodyBytes,
);
```

now, your image should appear in the pdf but you will have to resize your image if you want to fix height and width.